# Unable to use regex with pipe character in cucumber step definition

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have to use regular expression for number greater than or equal to 3 and that regex is

```
^([3-9]|\d{2,})$
```

But when I use this regex in cucumber step definion, I am getting error- "*Row must have the same cells count as table's header*"

[image]

As per my understanding, pipe character is creating problem in regex but if I try to escape using back slash, regex will be incorrect.

Comment: If you escape the pipe, why would the regex be incorrect?

Comment: yes M.P. Korstanje, we can not escape the pipe otherwise regex will be invalid. do you know how to fix above problem?

Comment: What happens to the regex when you escape the pipe? Did you look at it?